# heap near stack in /proc/id/maps

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory

I was playing with `malloc` in shared object in Linux, checking the memory layout at /proc/id/maps, which is like this:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep proc1)/maps
7f94331d0000-7f94331d1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 160882             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib2.so
7f94331d1000-7f94331d3000 ---p 00001000 00:00 160882             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib2.so
7f94331d3000-7f94333d0000 ---p 00000003 00:00 160882             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib2.so
7f94333d0000-7f94333d1000 r--p 00000000 00:00 160882             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib2.so
7f94333d1000-7f94333d2000 rw-p 00001000 00:00 160882             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib2.so
7f94333e0000-7f94333e1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 159995             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib1.so
7f94333e1000-7f94333e3000 ---p 00001000 00:00 159995             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib1.so
7f94333e3000-7f94335e0000 ---p 00000003 00:00 159995             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib1.so
7f94335e0000-7f94335e1000 r--p 00000000 00:00 159995             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib1.so
7f94335e1000-7f94335e2000 rw-p 00001000 00:00 159995             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/lib1.so
7f94335f0000-7f94337d7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 736305             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f94337d7000-7f94337e0000 ---p 001e7000 00:00 736305             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f94337e0000-7f94339d7000 ---p 000001f0 00:00 736305             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f94339d7000-7f94339db000 r--p 001e7000 00:00 736305             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f94339db000-7f94339dd000 rw-p 001eb000 00:00 736305             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f94339dd000-7f94339e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f94339f0000-7f94339f3000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 736328             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f94339f3000-7f94339f4000 ---p 00003000 00:00 736328             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f94339f4000-7f9433bf2000 ---p 00000004 00:00 736328             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f9433bf2000-7f9433bf3000 r--p 00002000 00:00 736328             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f9433bf3000-7f9433bf4000 rw-p 00003000 00:00 736328             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f9433c00000-7f9433c26000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 736281             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f9433c26000-7f9433c27000 r-xp 00026000 00:00 736281             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f9433e27000-7f9433e28000 r--p 00027000 00:00 736281             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f9433e28000-7f9433e29000 rw-p 00028000 00:00 736281             /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f9433e29000-7f9433e2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9433f70000-7f9433f73000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9433f80000-7f9433f82000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f9434000000-7f9434001000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 767020             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/proc1
7f9434200000-7f9434201000 r--p 00000000 00:00 767020             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/proc1
7f9434201000-7f9434202000 rw-p 00001000 00:00 767020             /mnt/c/SOmalloc/proc1
7fffd6fe0000-7fffd7001000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                  [heap]
7fffde8f5000-7fffdf0f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                  [stack]
7fffdf439000-7fffdf43a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]
```

The address of heap is at around `0x7fffd6fe0000`, which is quite near the stack. As far as I know, the heap is usually at a low address like `0x8402e60`(I used gdb to see it), and there is a huge gap between stack and heap.

FYI, the only "strange" thing I did is writing a function in a shared object to call `malloc`, and call this function in the program.

In lib1.c:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

void* lib1_malloc(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}
```

---

Update:
The compile options for lib1.c is:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o lib1.so lib1.c -g
```

And lib2.c just has the same function with a twist to the name: `lib2_malloc`

The compile options for proc1.c is:

```
gcc -o proc1 proc1.c -ldl -g
```

And proc1.c:

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void* handle1, *handle2;
    void* (*malloc1)(size_t);
    void* (*malloc2)(size_t);
    void* (*realloc1)(void*, size_t);
    void* (*realloc2)(void*, size_t);

    handle1 = dlopen("./lib1.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    handle2 = dlopen("./lib2.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    malloc1 = dlsym(handle1, "lib1_malloc");
    malloc2 = dlsym(handle2, "lib2_malloc");
    realloc1 = dlsym(handle1, "lib1_realloc");
    realloc2 = dlsym(handle2, "lib2_realloc");

    //write something into the heap
    char *tmp1 = malloc1(32 * sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        tmp1[i] = 1;
    char *tmp = malloc(64* sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        tmp[i] = 2;
    char *tmp2 = malloc2(32 * sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        tmp2[i] = 3;

    tmp1 = realloc1(tmp1, 64 * sizeof(char));
    tmp = realloc(tmp, 32 * sizeof(char));
    tmp2 = realloc2(tmp2, 64 * sizeof(char));

    char aaa; //use scanf to stall the program
    scanf("%c", &aaa);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that whatever I compile with the option -fPIC and/or the lib is static or dynamic. Can you say more about how you compile sources and make the lib and make *proc1*  and the OS you are on ?

Comment: You really call a gap of 120 MiB *near*? Bottom of stack is at 7fffde8f5000, and the heap ends at 0x7fffd7001000, so the gap is 0x7fffde8f5000 - 0x7fffd7001000 = 0x78f40000 = 126,828,544.  By all reasonable expectations, that gap is *normal*.

Comment: I agree it is not _near_, but as I mentioned, in other maps I've seen the heap is always at 
quite a low address instead of starting with `0x7fff...`. And my knowledge about program memory layout is that the space allocated for shared object should goes between heap and stack, which also differs from the result above. @None

Comment: I'm using WSL on Windows 10 1903, and Ubuntu version is 18.04. I will post the code and compile flags soon. @bruno

Comment: There is no expectation of the memory being laid out in any way whatsoever. So I’m not quite sure what’s the surprise: that the OS and the CRT did what they normally do? ASLR may be at play as well. Expect nothing. Stack and heap can be anywhere.

Comment: But you do know that WSL is just an emulation of Linux?

Comment: I open up a VM and things just go as expected... WSL sure has some subtle problems. Thanks @LorinczyZsigmond